HTML Jinja2 for loop not showing the items on my postgresql+python flask web app
I'm trying to make a simple web app. On the frontpage, I want to show the top 10 restaurants in order by their average rating, but I've failed to do so. The database query gives me the correct table of restaurants in descending order. When I run it in the terminal, on the web app, it only shows "No restaurants available".
Here's the sql query.
:
def order_by_rating():
        sql = text("""
                SELECT r.id, r.name, ROUND(AVG(rv.stars), 2) AS average_rating
                FROM restaurants r
                LEFT JOIN reviews rv ON r.id = rv.restaurant_id
                GROUP BY r.id, r.name
                ORDER BY average_rating DESC
                LIMIT 10
        """)
        result = db.session.execute(sql)
        ratings = result.fetchall()
        return ratings


Here's the Flask route
@app.route("/top_restaurants")
def top_restaurants():
    ratings = restaurants.order_by_rating()
    print("Ratings", ratings)
    return render_template("index.html", ratings=ratings)

And the html template:
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if session.user_id %}
You are logged in with username <b>{{ session.username }}</b> <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
You are not logged in. <a href="/login">Login</a>
{% endif %}

{% if session.user_id %}
<p>
<form action="/search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search for a restaurant">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

    <p>Top 10 restaurants by average rating:</p>
    <ul>
    {% if ratings %}
        {% for restaurant in ratings %}
            <li><a href="/restaurant/{{ restaurant.id }}">{{ restaurant[1] }}</a> - {{ restaurant[2] }}/5</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <li>No restaurants available</li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>

{% endif %}
{% if session.user_id and session.user_role == "admin" %}
<h3>Admin actions</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/add">Add a new restaurant</a></li>
    <li><a href="/remove">Remove a restaurant</a></li>
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}


And the database tables:

CREATE TABLE restaurants (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    location TEXT,
    opening_hours TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    cuisine TEXT
);


CREATE TABLE reviews(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users,
    restaurant_id INTEGER REFERENCES restaurants,
    stars INTEGER,
    comment TEXT
);

Thank you!
I've tried to print debug lines but nothing comes up. I also tried this
   <p>Top 10 restaurants by average rating:</p>
    <ul>
    {% if ratings %}
        {% for restaurant in ratings %}
            <li><a href="/restaurant/{{ restaurant.id }}">{{ restaurant.name }}</a> - {{ restaurant.average_rating }}/5</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <li>No restaurants available</li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>

